# Error: No module named pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Estoy tratando de instalar pygame en mi python 2.7. Lo hago en este python porque por alguna razon si trato de instalar pip en el python 3.7 no me deja. Desde la terminal introduje:

```
sudo pip install pygame
```

Y supuestamente lo instaló bien, pero cuando trato de hacer el import me dice:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ejemplo.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
ImportError: No module named pygame
```

si trato de hacer otra vez `sudo pip install pygame` me dice:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pygame in /home/cesar/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (1.9.4)
```

Además , si trato de ejecutar `pip list` y busco pygame me sale instalado:

```
pygame                        1.9.4
```

Que puede estar ocurriendo? Por qué me dice que el requerimiento ya se cumple si no es capaz de importar el módulo?

Comment: Primero, se debe evitar en instalar módulos con permisos de superusuario. Se debería instalar para el usuario y mejor aún usar un entorno virtual y no instalar módulos en la instalación del sistema. Bien dicho esto, seguramente tienes varios interpretes instalados, segurament epip instañl aen Python 2.7 y pero usas Python 3 para ejecutar , pygame está instalado en el interprete Python2 situado en `/home/cesar/.local/lib/`. En el script donde intentas importarlo haz `import sys; print(sys.executable)` y mira la ruta del interprete que usas. Debes instalar Pygame en en ese interprete.

Comment: Prueba a instalar con `python3.7 -m pip install pygame --user`. Te recomiendo instalar siempre así, te aseguras de estar usando pip del interprete adecuado de forma explícita. Puedes incluso usar la ruta absoluta que te retornas `sys.executable ` en lugar de `python3.7` por si no tienes el PATH correctamente configurado.

Comment: Siempre lo hago con sudo porque si trato de hacerlo como me indicas me dice: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permiso denegado: '/home/cesar/.local/include/python3.7m'
Check the permissions.

a que se puede deber esto?

Comment: Cesar no se como instalaste Python pero no deberías tener problemas con  permisos en tu propio usuario.... Deberías corregir los permisos del directorio primero.

Comment: Voy a tratar de hace eso primero, gracias